# ArrayAdapter- Getview() causes an error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, getview

I have a little problem I couldn't solve. I've searched and I tried a lot of things, Unfortunately no results. 
Getview is causing an error

The line causnig an error is this one below in ArrayAdapter:

*val tvCopiedText:TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.tv_copiedText)*

[image]

Here is the code:

**ArrayAdapter**

```
class MyArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<CopiedText> {
constructor(context: Context, resource:Int, copiedTexts: List<CopiedText>) : super(context, resource, copiedTexts) {
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var view: View? = null
    val copiedText:CopiedText = getItem(position)
    if (convertView == null){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)

    }

    val tvCopiedText:TextView = view!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_copiedText)
    val tvTime:TextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_time)
    //val tvCopiedText = retView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_copiedText)
    //val tvCopiedText = retView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_copiedText)

    tvCopiedText.text = copiedText.ctText
    tvTime.text = copiedText.ctTime.toString()

    return  view
}
```

}

**Adapter in MainActivity:**

```
ctAdapter = MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, listCopiedText)
    myListView.adapter = ctAdapter
```

**item_layout:**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_copiedText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Here will be the copied Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Time"/>
```

Comment: Never screenshot the log, post it as code, please.

Comment: Which one the affected line is would be good to know.

Comment: @leoderprofi this öne in ArrayAdapter:
val tvCopiedText:TextView = view!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_copiedText)

Comment: @G.K. Ök, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a null pointer is because you are not assigning the `view` variable to anything in case `convertView` is not null. Change this code

```
var view: View? = null
    val copiedText:CopiedText = getItem(position)
    if (convertView == null){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)

    }
```

to

```
var view: View? = convertView
    val copiedText:CopiedText = getItem(position)
    if (view == null){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You make use of the double exclamation mark operator and get a `NullpointerException`, it’s the price you have to pay ;-)
It is used for converting nullable types (T?) to non-nullable types (T) in an unsafe way.

```
view!!.findViewById(R.id.tv_copiedText)
```

Your `view` is null and thus the exception is thrown. You should consider applying reasonable nullability handling instead. There’s almost always a [better solution](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) than `!!`.